# I am trying to embed a patch in a bash script - can't get patch to read the patch from a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, patch

```
read -d '' PATCH_OS <<EOF

//PATCH//TEXT//

EOF

patch -b < ${PATCH_OS}
```

This fails:

```
./script.sh: line 39: --- //PATCH//TEXT//
```

(line 39 is "patch -b < ${PATCH_OS}"")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how redirections work. `<` redirects input from a *file*; if you specify a variable then its contents are taken to be the *file name*. You'd be looking for `<<<` instead. And don't forget to put quotes around the `"$variable"`, otherwise bash will split its value by spaces.

(Except in your example script the variable is useless. Just use `patch -b <<EOF` directly.)